# How to integrate realm model with the gloss model in effective harmony as I am facing this issue

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, gloss

Here is my sample code, It gives an nil on the link as self.init() called get property what is the alternate way to do this?

```
class channel : Object, Gloss.Decodable {
var id:String?
var channelName:String?
dynamic var links: Links? = nil
public required convenience init?(json: JSON) {
    self.init()
    self.id = "id" <~~ json
    self.channelName = "channelName" <~~ json
    self.links = "links" <~~ json
}
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}
var getLinks:Links{

    get{

        return self.links!  //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    }
}

class Links: Object, Gloss.Decodable {
    var href:String?
    var rel:String?
    var method:String?


    required convenience init(json: JSON) {

        self.init()
        self.href = "href" <~~ json
        self.rel = "rel" <~~ json
        self.method = "method" <~~ json

    }
}
}
```

I could not find the way to solved it out. Any one having same problem, or suggest some way out.
Thank You!

Updated Links as

```
    var getLinks:Links?{

    get{

        guard let link = self.links else{
            return nil
        }
        return link
    }
}
```

This gives an error: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Property 'links' is declared as '_TtCC6WTV_GO11ChannelList5Links', which is not a supported RLMObject property type. All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject**

Comment: Why are you force unwrapping a property that can take an optional value? When you call `getLinks` are you sure the value of `links` should be non-nil? Which Swift version are you using?  In any case, your Realm properties are missing the `dynamic` keyword, but if you are using Swift 4, you also need to add the `@objc` keyword.

Comment: I am using swift version 3.2 and my problem is when I call self.init() inside convenience init() then it call get property and initially self.link is nil and it crashes before using realm and there was not any issue as I am calling required init().

Comment: I have updated links and still could not solved it.